# sqlalchemy - how to sort dictionary text field by a value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class model define like this:

```
class Order(orm.Model):
    __tablename__ = "order_index"
    id = orm.Column(orm.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    detail = orm.Column(orm.TEXT)
query = Order.query.filter(some_filter)
```

the detail row is in dictionary format.(etc:`{"status": 1, "win_price": 0,..}` )
How do I sort the query result by a key of `win_price`?

Comment: That'd depend on the DB you are using.

Comment: mysql, im trying to get a custom manual way

Comment: MySQL has JSON support, so why not use it? That'd make your life a _lot_ easier. I guess you can use a CAST and then access the relevant field.

Comment: you mean switch .text to .json?

Comment: Preferably, but as stated before, you can CAST if your schema is already set in stone.

Comment: my schema is not able to change now due to a large amount of data exists. another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your schema cannot change, you'll have to resort to using a [CAST](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.cast) to [JSON](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.JSON):

```
In [20]: session.query(Order.detail).\
    ...:     order_by(Order.detail.cast(JSON)['win_price']).\
    ...:     all()
```

which will emit the following SQL:

```
SELECT order_index.detail AS order_index_detail 
FROM order_index
ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(CAST(order_index.detail AS JSON), %(param_1)s)
```

with params:

```
{'param_1': '$."win_price"'}
```

And if you happen to be using SQLAlchemy older than 1.1 (which introduced MySQL JSON support), but are using MySQL 5.7.8 or above, then you could form the required query manually:

```
In [13]: session.query(Order.detail).\
    ...:     order_by(func.json_extract(Order.detail, '$."win_price"')).\
    ...:     all()
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work properly". You mention imports, did you import the `JSON` type? `from sqlalchemy import JSON`. JSON support is relatively new in MySQL, I believe. What version are you using?

Comment: `query = table.query.filter(generate_filter(query_dct, table)) query.order_by(table.detail.cast(JSON)['win_price'])` I just dont know what's going on. the server just stop working with no log

Comment: You mentioned you have large amounts of data. How large? How selective the generated filters are? Could it be trying to order the whole table, or a significant portion of it? If that is the case, you might have to create generated columns that are generated from `detail` in similar manner, index them, and use those for ordering.

Comment: the generated filter working fine. I just want to show you that i use the `query` for further `.orderby()`. i found the problem is that after i `from sqlalchemy import JSON` the system crash with no log

Comment: That's quite unexpected... What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: its is 1.0.12 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163772/discussion-between-ilja-everila-and-pawan).